# Enhanced Object Inspector Expert plug-in for delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, ide, add-in, inspector

I remember some guy made his one IDE expert, replacing stock object inspector adding filtering and such

But i frankly forgot its name

It was so generic that googling i only can get for runtime clones of OI, not that IDE add-in.

Comment: damn it, and how should i mark that BOTH answers were correct ?
at least now this link is hopefully persistent on SO :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are thinking of Uwe Schuster and [Object Inspector Expert](http://www.bitcommander.de/blog/index.php/2012/07/15/oi-rev-5/)

Comment: The page cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 15):

You probably mean Uwe Schuster's [Object Inspector Expert](http://www.bitcommander.de/blog/index.php/2012/07/15/oi-rev-5/).

Comment: exactly. But he was bit faster and i cannot give you both half a checkmark on SO :-/

Comment: @TOndrej SO cheats on you :-P

Comment: No, it says clearly my answer was posted earlier. ;-)

Comment: I guess we just have to remember it for the future, that your reputation score really ought to have been 10 points higher. :)

Comment: then it cheatign at both of us, to me it shown 1 minute advantage for Nick. But now you both have "1 hour ago" and it is a tie

Comment: I think it showed you 2 minutes advantage for me. You only appear to have made the same mistake as many others often do - interpret "25 minutes ago" as earlier than "27 minutes ago". ;-) If you want to see the exact timestamp, hover your mouse over the "1 hour ago" (or whatever) text and see the tooltip.

Comment: @Arioch'The TOndrej answered first (:

Comment: Nicholas is a newb and needs the points.

Comment: TOndrej did bet me :( but as Warren P commented, I need the points (didn't like to be called a newb just because I don't have points but I will live :) ). I am happy for the tick to go to TOndrej- The points don't matter to me that much. :)

Comment: I would be happy with an object inspector that did not have a extremely annoying non-resizable window that persists in showing so that the data you want is not displayed and you have to fiddle with scrollbars.

Comment: the expert in question is having text filtering

Delphi 5 introduced properties categories but they never been vastly used. In Delphi XE2 i cannot even bring 5 different *ImageIndex properties in TButton to be seen close to each other. Withouut text filtering :-)

Comment: @TOndrej - exactly one minute difference. But ahem, how can "25 minutes ago" be *later* than "27 minutes ago" ? Is SO nuts ?

Comment: 25 minutes ago _is_ later than 27 minutes ago. ;-)